# Handle "500" server error type during API request using rentrez

Tags: r, http, bioinformatics, http-status-code-500

I am trying to recover some IDs linked to names using the `rentrez` package that is a R wrapper over the `entrez` API using this code (short list of query as an example):

```
vect_names <- c("Theileria sergenti","Dipodascus ambrosiae","Dipodascus armillariae","Dipodascus macrosporus")


idseq <- lapply(vect_names, function(x){
  query <- entrez_search(db = "taxonomy", term = x)
  return(query$ids)
})
```

Now, this code works for me as long as I get no server errors (type : `500`) which stops my requests. For small amounts of queries it is not a problem but I have around 40k queries to send so it will encounter the error for sure.
This is the error :

```
Erreur : HTTP failure: 500
{"error":"error forwarding request","api-key":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","type":"ip",
"status":"ok"
```

I did some research and I think I need to wrap this code into a `try/except` function. However, the documentation is pretty scary to me and I don't see how I can replicate the server error I have  so I could build a reproducible example with the error. Also  because my full request will last several hours, testing multiple versions of a try/except until I am sure my code handles the error could take a long time.

So what I am looking for here is a version of this first piece of code that will continue to request the same vector element until it gets the result for it (until the HTTP failure is solved, which should take a matter of seconds).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I needed to use the `tryCatch` function coupled with `Sys.sleep` :

```
idseq <- lapply(vect_names, function(x){
  
  tryCatch(
    {
      query <- entrez_search(db = "taxonomy", term = x)
      return(ifelse(is.na(query), NA, query$ids))
    },
    
    error = function(e)
    {
      Sys.sleep(60) # If error (most probably type 500 serveur), sleep 60scd then redo
      query <- entrez_search(db = "taxonomy", term = x)
      return(ifelse(is.na(query), NA, query$ids))
    }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample list you provided doesn't give an error for me, but you can use tryCatch like this

```
idseq <- lapply(vect_names, function(x) {
    query <- tryCatch(entrez_search(db = "taxonomy", term = x), error= function(e) NA)
    return(ifelse(is.na(query), NA, query$ids))
}
```

if there's an error `query` will be NA, so I changed the returned value to check for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you were close! Yes, the issue is a server error from their side so the request must take a few hours to get the error.